# ASP.NET Web Site Project with User Uploaded Files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I have an ASP .NET Web Site Project that is being moved into TFS. There is a folder that is used for user uploaded files (e.g., company logos, excel spread sheets, etc.) that need to be kept. I'm trying to figure out a good way to manage these files without placing the folder in TFS (it's really big), and make it easy for new developers to grab the folder structure to their local machines for development.

I was thinking of doing the following and was wondering if this is a good way of doing it, or if there are better alternatives:

1. Create a script which will, when executed, create the folder structure of the storage folder. This would be placed in source control.
2. New developers could grab this file and execute it on their local machine.
3. To make sure the folder is added to source control, get the developer to remove it from their local project.

Answer (score 1):

Store the folder on a NAS - no need for the files to be part of the source-controlled code.